# Paypal Missing Payer Address With Subscription Payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am capturing subscription payments with Paypal, sadly neither the IPN message or the API call to `/v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}` shows me the address of the payer because I set no_shipping = 1 during the subscription creation since I am selling a digital service.

What is the correct way to solve this? I need the address for tax purposes to create an invoice, should I require a shipping address for a digital product?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an address, collect it yourself separately from PayPal or do not specify no_shipping=1. Those are your options.